# `Make` module constructor pattern in OCaml module system

Tags: module, ocaml, functor

In the library [higher_kind](https://github.com/janestreet/higher_kinded), which uses Yallop & White's paper (cf [oleg's page](https://okmij.org/ftp/ML/higher-kind-poly.html) for references on that), I notice something interesting using the OCaml module system (for which I am just getting acquainted with)

As far as I understand (taking the example in the readme as an illustration), the library creates a unique internal name, which forces the user to call `Make`

```ml
Higher_kinded.Make (Base.Option)
```

to build any module of signature

```ml
Higher_kinded.S with type 'a t := 'a option
```

`Make` is not just a convenience to augment a module. You can't build a module of the resulting signature by hand. So this looks like a smart *type* constructor, akin to smart *value* constructor of an abstract data type.

Is there a name for this pattern ? Does it generalizes or compose in some meaningful way ?

Edit : This is used also in [GADTs for the OCaml Masses](https://homepage.divms.uiowa.edu/%7Eastump/papers/scott-paper.pdf)

(Details of the mechanism below, hoping I did not get confused)

---

- [Higher_kinded_intf](https://github.com/janestreet/higher_kinded/blob/master/src/higher_kinded_intf.ml) contains a functor building a module containing only signatures which are parameterized by a type in the parameter module.

```ml
module Higher_kinded_module_types (Higher_kinded : T1) = struct

...

 module type S = sig
    type 'a t
    type higher_kinded

    val inject : 'a t -> ('a -> higher_kinded) Higher_kinded.t (* from the parameter module *)
    val project : ('a -> higher_kinded) Higher_kinded.t -> 'a t
  end

...

end
```

It also contains a module signature

```ml
module type Higher_kinded = sig

type 'a t (* some t should be in scope *)

...

(*line 196*)
include module type Higher_kinded_module_types (struct
      type nonrec 'a t = 'a t (*propagates that t in scope to be Higher_kinded.t *)
    end)

module Make (X : sig
    type 'a t
 end) : S with type 'a t := 'a X.t

...

end
```

to which the module definition `higher_kinded.ml` should conform to (via an include in the `.mli` file)

- [higher_kinded.ml](https://github.com/janestreet/higher_kinded/blob/master/src/higher_kinded.ml) contains the implementation and the abstract type

```ml
open Higher_kinded_intf


type 'a t (* THE t of the implementation *)

... 

include Higher_kinded_module_types (struct
    type nonrec 'a t = 'a t (*propagates that specific t in scope *)
  end)

...

module Make (X : sig
    type 'a t
  end) : S with type 'a t := 'a X.t = struct
  type higher_kinded

  external inject : 'a X.t -> ('a -> higher_kinded) t = "%identity"
  external project : ('a -> higher_kinded) t -> 'a X.t = "%identity"
end
```